# Prove that B is a subring of A

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need help with this proof please.

Let $A$ be a ring, $f: A \to A$ a homomorphism, and $B=\{x \in A: f(x)=x\}$. Prove that $B$ is a subring of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

A subset $B$ of a ring $A$ is a subring of $A$ if and only if each of the following hold:

- $S\neq\varnothing$
- $a+(-b)\in B$ whenever $a,b\in B$
- $ab\in B$ whenever $a,b\in B$

In this setting, we have a ring homomorphism $f:A\to A$ and $B=\{x\in A:f(x)=x\}$. To prove that $B$ is a subring of $A$ we need to prove that $B$ has each of the three above properties.

To prove that $S\neq\varnothing$, note that $f(\mathbf 1_A)=\mathbf 1_B$ by definition.

Can you prove the other two required properties?